# make a javascript variable into php variable without refreshing page

Tags: php, javascript, html

with the code I have I can echo:`<a id='test'>`
and it displays what was typed, however I need to make`<a id='test'>` into a variable so I can use it for mysql query's etc. is this possible at all?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function email(){
   var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
   document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = input;
 }
</script>

<html>
  <p><input type='text' id='input' value='' />
    <input type='button' onclick='email()' value='submit'/></p>
</html>

<?php
    $info="<a id='text'>"//make this a variable;
    echo $info;
?>
```

Comment: if you dont want a refresh, look into `ajax` like jquery's `.post`

Comment: Not directly like that. It is possible with AJAX.

Comment: The server executes the PHP. The output is HTML and is sent to client, the browser. It parses the HTML and executes the JavaScript. So, PHP is executed on the server, JavaScript on the client. There is no way to mingle those languages in this scenario. As already mentioned, you can use AJAX to send HTTP requests to the server in the background. This question is asked *a lot* and you can find many helpful, related questions if you search for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert JavaScript variable value into PHP variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482418/how-to-convert-javascript-variable-value-into-php-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[using AJAX with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will help you make a simple call to the server, without page reloading. Then you can send any variables to a PHP file that will store them in your database.